# vite config for markdown loader. Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, markdown, vite

I'm building my vue app also trying use this [vite-plugin-md](https://github.com/antfu/vite-plugin-md) as my markdown loader.

```js
/* vite.config.js */

import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { Markdown } from 'vite-plugin-md'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue({
      include: [/\.vue$/, /\.md$/], // <--
    }),
    Markdown(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})
```

But when I add the code provided in `READMD.md` and `npm run dev`. It comes errors below

```bash
failed to load config from /route/md-demo/vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in /route/md-demo/node_modules/@yankeeinlondon/happy-wrapper/package.json
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
    at exportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:295:10)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:575:13)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:538:36)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:607:31)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1025:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:885:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/route/md-demo/node_modules/vite-plugin-md/dist/index.cjs:18031:28)
```

I've tried use error keyword for searching related post and use `npm update`. Still won't work. Need help.

### Late Update:

For anyone who hit the same issue. Add `"type": "module"` to the package.json to resolve this issue. Found in the [discussion thread](https://github.com/antfu/vite-plugin-md/discussions/126).

Comment: Yep same here, not sure why this is suddenly broken.

Comment: So it worked before?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and could resolve it by adding this key-value pair to my `package.json` file:

```
"module": true
```

Note that after applying this change, you may need to rename some of your files with `.js` extension to `.cjs` extension. Some examples are `.eslintrc.js`, `.commitlintrc.js`, `.releaserc.js`, `postcss.config.js`, and `tailwind.config.js`. But don't worry! Errors will guide you to identify which files need this change.

I guess you've migrated from an old version of Vite to a newer version, and by the old version I mean a version earlier than 3.x.x.

However, `vite-plugin-md` can't work with the old versions of Vite. Besides, Vite didn't put `"module": true` in `package.json` file in its old versions, but it does so in the newer versions. So, most of the people don't encounter this issue because they've already started their project with a fresh version of Vite.

Answer (score 1):

The package is not `vite-plugin-md`. The right one is `vite-plugin-vue-markdown`.

The `ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED` always indicates a missing imported package.